# pagination script not displaying more than 3 links

Tags: php, pagination

I am using the php script below to generate comments from mysql, and also paginating it at the same time. I have 19 rows in the database, and I have set 5 comments per page in the variable. so I should have 4 links i.e. `[1] [2] [3] [4]` . but i am only getting 3 links 
. I do not get any error. even when I set per page to 2, I still get 3 links.

```
 <?php    
         $per_page = 5;
         $total_query = $query = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM comments ")  or die (mysql_error());

         $pages =  ceil(mysql_result($total_query, 0) / $total_query);

         $page = (isset($_GET['page'])) ? (int)$_GET['page'] : 1;

         $start = ($page - 1) *  $per_page ;

         $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM comments LIMIT $start, $per_page")  or die (mysql_error());   

         while ($comment = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {

         <?php echo $comment['owner'] ; ?>

         <?php echo htmlspecialchars($comment['body']) ;?>

         <?php $date = date_create($comment['created']); 
         echo  date_format($date, 'F j, Y g:i a'); ?>  

          if ($pages >= 1 && $page <= $pages) {

     for ($x = 1; $x<=$pages; $x++) {

     echo ($x == $page)  ? '<a href="http://127.0.0.1/page.php?page='.$x.'">' . $x 

.'</a> </span>' : '<a href="http://127.0.0.1/page.php?page='.$x.'"> [' . $x .' ]</a> ';

  }
  }
  ?>
```

Comment: This line looks a bit weird: `$pages =  ceil(mysql_result($total_query, 0) / $total_query);` Should you be dividing by `$per_page`?

Comment: @JohnC got it, my answer post was a little slow. ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your line:

```
$pages =  ceil(mysql_result($total_query, 0) / $total_query);
```

is getting the result and dividing by... `$total_query`, which should be `$per_page`.